# Coverting text from one Column to a year date format in another column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have two columns called "LC" and "LC Datum".

"LC" contains text value's like 2015, 2016 and so on. These are actually years and need to be converted/transfered to another column called "LC DATUM", where the text value will be a date year value.

When I try to go in the Attribute table into the Field calculator. And then into the Column "LC Datum" and try to set the expression "LC" in the "LC Datum" Column it gives the value NULL. This is strange because I clearly see a result of the execution in the calculator window. I assume I need to do an extra conversion of my data. But how do I do this?

Edit: As the last thing I also need to note that there are null value's in my LC column.

Comment: Expression `year("LC")` could work?

Comment: No It does not work for me because the I says the expresion is not vallid. It cannot convert it to Date Time format...

Comment: You are right, sorry. Only way I can think of is (1) create or update "LC_Datum" field by an expression `to_date(concat("LC", '-01-01'))` and then (2) Open `Layer Properties | Fields` and click on [Text Edit] to change the widget to Date/Time which allows `custom` to `yyyy` format.

Comment: ...Um your case I think will work but the problem is that some value's in LC column are NULL causing an error to occur. How do i get past that then?

Comment: Not a clean way, but probably I would put something like `CASE WHEN length("LC") < 1 THEN to_date('1111-01-01') ELSE to_date(concat("LC", '-01-01')) END` and deal with the dummy (Year 1111) afterwards...

Comment: By the way you can edit your question to highlight that your LC has NULL to gain more attention to the issue.

Comment: Try using `to_date("LC" || '-01-01')` instead. This ignores NULL values.

Comment: @Kazuhito - Kindly post your [comment](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236445/coverting-text-from-one-column-to-a-year-date-format-in-another-column-in-qgis#comment368278_236445) as an answer but replace `to_date(concat("LC", '-01-01')` with `to_date("LC" || '-01-01')` since you pretty much got it right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from @Joseph , this is the proposed steps.

1. In the `Field Calculator`, create or update `"LC_Datum"` field by an expression `to_date("LC" || '-01-01')`. Close the Attribute table.
2. Open `Layer Properties` and select `Fields` tab. Click on [Text Edit] of the `LC_Datum` to change the widget to `Date/Time` which allows *Widget display* option to `custom` and manually set it to **yyyy** format.

As data type of "LC_Datum" was set to Date, it expected date formatted inputs like *2015-01-01*, and rejected *2015*.